# What exactly is the php.ini memory_limit?

Tags: php, memory

I often saw the php.ini memory_limit but I haven't found the answer to my question.

What **EXACTLY** is the memory_limit in php.ini?

Please post an detailed example.
Thanks :)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit

Answer (score 1):

PHP’s memory_limit setting is not a storage space where multiple PHP scripts pool form or grow. The 'memory_limit' directive sets the maximum amount of memory that a PHP script can use. Note that this is dynamically allocated, and not reserved memory. If a script exceeds this value, PHP will report a fatal error.

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of x bytes exhausted (tried to allocate x bytes)

The error means that the allowed memory limit of x bytes configured on your server(memory_limit=xM) was reached while the PHP script tried to allocate y bytes.

Answer (score 0):

It's the limit of the memory of the php script. It avoids than bad code fill the server memory, crashing it.